# Polygon function inverting shaded area of min-max threshold

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I'm trying to create a shaded area within the constraints of minimum and maximum values in R.

My issue is that the polygon function I'm using is not shadding in the internal area of the minimum and maximum constraints (the grey shaded area in the image below). Also I'm using the exact same code for other sections of the plot and it's working perfectly (the red and blue shaded areas).

I've tried the same code with another dataset and produced the same result; I checked the dataset in excel and the min and max values are correct. I've also tried changing the order of the max and min and produced the same result.

The code:

```
polygon(c(fd$Date,rev(fd$Date)),c(fd$FD0_historical_max,rev(fd$FD0_historical_min)), col = "grey", border = FALSE)
polygon(c(fd$Date,rev(fd$Date)),c(fd$FD0_RCP_8.5_max,rev(fd$FD0_RCP_8.5_min)), col = "tomato", border = FALSE)
polygon(c(fd$Date,rev(fd$Date)),c(fd$FD0_RCP_4.5_max,rev(fd$FD0_RCP_4.5_min)), col = "skyblue", border = FALSE)
```

[Plot with shaded areas- the grey area should be like the red and blue shadded areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va8OM.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION:** polygon(c(**rev**(fd$Date),fd$Date),c(**rev**(fd$FD0_historical_max),fd$FD0_historical_min), col = "grey", border = FALSE)

[correct shadding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLZLT.png)

Comment: `polygon` assumes the polygon is drawn counter-clockwise.  You probably drew it clockwise, but since your example isn't reproducible, I'm just guessing.

Comment: @user2554330 is right - for your first line try `c(rev(fd$Date), df$Date)`

Comment: Yes! Thank you both.